# Access/check Spring Security hierarchical roles programmatically

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my Grails project I defined multiple [hierarchical roles](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/14%20Hierarchical%20Roles.html) using the Spring Security plugin e.g. `ROLE_USER > SOME_OTHER_ROLE`. When securing controller methods using the `@Secured` annotation it works just fine. However, I also would like to check the role programmatically in my code for one use case. Using the following approach I always get a `false` even though the user inherits the role through hierarchical role definition:

```
request.isUserInRole('SOME_OTHER_ROLE')
```

Also the following calls never directly return the inherited roles:

```
SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication?.authorities
springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
```

Is there a way of checking if the user also has the inherited role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug (or at least an omission) in `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` which adds a request wrapper to implement the `isUserInRole` method.

You can use the `roleVoter` bean's `extractAuthorities` method. Add a dependency injection for it (`def roleVoter`) and then call

```
def allRoles = roleVoter.extractAuthorities(
        SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication)
```

Comment: Thanks, Burt! Works like a charm. I will open a ticket for this soon.

Comment: This is the [Jira ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1925) for Spring Security for future reference.